# Why does graphics.clearRect change its behaviour?

Tags: image, swing

I was on the way of making a picasa like photo viewer and later an image editor.i used JFrame and alpha channel to set background transparent.but while moving or zooming in/out ,as i had to draw it on different location and clear the previous image i used clearRect and faced the problem.

the **[oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html)** says it clears the rect and restores the background color.

on some trials the clearRect clears the area to background color.But while continuous events like mouse-dragging its turning the color of cleared area to black and causing this:

```
 `
```

thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> .i used JFrame and alpha channel to set background transparent.

Don't use alpha for complete transparency. Instead just use:

```
panel.setOpaque( false );
```

If you are using semi transparency then check out [Backgrounds With Transparency](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/31/backgrounds-with-transparency/). It will explain the problems with transparent background and provide a couple of solutions.

The basic problem is that transparency breaks the painting contract with Swing components because the background is not cleared entirely before child components are painted.

Comment: the panel idea took me to what i was looking for.Thanks for that.